# free shipping chekcout

Tags: magento-1.9, category, checkout, shipping, coupon

I setup some category with free shipping but the thing is the free shipping is applied on other shipping option such as expedited.

Is there any way I can make free shipping on the standard shipping only for the category. **Please let me know.**

Answer (score 3):

The best way you can use is `Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rule`.
In `Actions` tab set `Free Shipping` value to `For matching items only`. Then set your condition bellow.

**In example:**

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :  
Category  is  5
```

You can set additional rules in `Conditions` tab.

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer. I have done same and the free shipping is worked. But what I want is the expedited is remained as charged, not free.